# Manually deleting and using a dll in C# web service

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a Web Service in C# and am an outright novice. Please pardon me if what I have asked is dead silly. I have a set of dlls that the Web Service uses. What I want to achieve is as follows:

1. Let us assume that the dlls are first.dll, second.dll and common.dll
2. common.dll is referenced in first.dll and second.dll (common.dll contains interfaces that are implemented in first.dll and second.dll)
3. common.dll has a static dictionary of the types of classes contained in first.dll and second.dll. Classes from this dictionary are instantiated as required.
4. Whenever I have a new common.dll ready for release, I want to manually delete the common.dll file and replace it with the new release of common.dll **while the system is live/running.**

Presently, I am getting the following error when I am attempting to perform step 4:
"This action can't be completed because the file is open in vshost32-clr2.exe"

It is so that I am missing something completely?

Comment: Why would you assume you could overwrite a file while it is open/being used?

Comment: dont run the web service in visual studio. Try to host it in IIS.

Comment: @Frank, it is not about a file being open / used, it is about a dll getting referenced.

Comment: @Sandeep, will try that as also pointed out by Alexei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

24/7 availability is not a cheap thing - do you really need one?

One of easy approaches is to re-route traffic to different servers when you upgraded your application. You get both servers running and verified that new one is OK and than switch traffic to go to new one. You can use DNS entries or some software/hardware router to redirect traffic.

If you really want to replace assemblies on the fly you can do that. You may need enough layers of proxy objects and potentially load your final assemblies in custom app-domain.  You may be able to get away with simply copying DLL to root folder of Web Site on IIS and hope that app-domain recycle will work correctly and satisfy your "always live" requirement.

Note: "manually delete" and "the system is live/running all the time" should not appear together for the same system... unless you know of a person who can flawlessly perform the same boring tens of steps multiple times at any time of day...

Comment: Thanks @Alexei. The possibilities you have provided in your answer has given me a direction to my thought process. I will think over "24/7 availability is not a cheap thing - do you really need one", though :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to shut down the hosting website. Copy in the new assembly. Then restart the website.

Comment: Not true; in our system, we deploy new versions of .dll files on-the-fly all the time. Also, the asker wants the system to stay live.

Comment: @OmegaMan, Filip's answer is in the correct direction as far as my question is concerned.

Comment: @AakashRoy, something is referencing the assembly during runtime and it is being loaded in memory. Until you find what that is and reverse it, you will continue to have this problem.